# Storing onclick function into session

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am facing an error in my "save_answer_in_session.php" page.`Undefined index: questionno in C:\wamp64\www\Exam\forajax\save_answer_in_session.php on line 5`
I have declared the index "questionno" by GET method in my ajax code. Where i am worng?
This is my input field of radio type

```
<input type="radio" name="r1" id="r1" value="<?php echo $opt1; ?>" onclick="radioclick(this.value,<?php echo $question_no; ?>)"
<?php 
if ($ans==$opt1) {
    echo "Checked!!!";
    }
    ?>>
```

And this is my ajax code which is calling that value and sending it to the page "save_answer_in_session.php"

```
function radioclick(radiovalue,questionno){
            var xmlhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","forajax/save_answer_in_session.php?questionno="+ questionno +"&value1="+radiovalue,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
```

And this is my "save_answer_in_session.php" page

```
    <?php 
session_start();

$questionno = $_GET['questionno'];

$value1 = $_GET['value1'];

$_SESSION['answer'][$questionno]=$value1;

?>
```

Basically i am making an online quiz system...what is want to do is one first question and their options appear and user clicks on one option and go to next question,it should save that previous option into session.

Comment: And so what exactly is your question?

Comment: you don't seem to have asked a question or described a problem. It's unclear what you need help with. Is there an issue with the code you've posted? (By which I mean an actual problem, not that you just haven't implemented some feature yet.)

Comment: @ADyson just edited my question. I want to store onclick function into session but this code isn't working for me.

Comment: Ok but "isn't working" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "isn't working" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that "isn't working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? Do you see error messages anywhere? What did you expect to happen instead? Narrow down the issue for us please (because we cannot debug your code - only you can do that. If you don't know how to debug AJAX requests, or PHP applications, now would be the ideal time to go and learn.)

Comment: @PatrickQ Question edited. This code isn't working for me to store onclick function into session.

Comment: @ADyson this is the problem. When i select or click on one option this code should store that value in session and then click next button to go for the next question and after that when i get back to previous question that option i selected before should be same as "checked". But nothing is happening.

Comment: Do you understand how to use your browser's Developer Tools to see what is happening - i.e. look for error messages, look for AJAX errors, and step through your javascript one line at a time? If "nothing" is happening there's a good chance that's because you aren't looking in the right place. You need to watch and see if the AJAX call happens successfully, to write the value to the session. It would never show anything on the screen anyway for that part of the functionality.

Comment: P.S you said first "this code should store that value in session"...it looks like the code above should probably do that (subject to possible errors which we are talking about now). But "after that when i get back to previous question that option i selected before should be same as "checked""...to be honest it's not clear how the code you've shown would actually achieve that. I'm guessing you've got some other code which might help to do it? But first, please focus on determining whether the value is being written to the session or not. Then worry about the next part afterwards.

Comment: Building on ADyson's comments, take this one step at a time.  When you click the radio button, do you see a request made in your browser's network inspector? If so, is, does it have the expected values? Does it have a success status code (200)?

Comment: @PatrickQ i am getting this is error in my "save_answer_in_session.php" page.
Undefined index: questionno in C:\wamp64\www\Exam\forajax\save_answer_in_session.php on line 5.

While i have declared this "questionno" properly by GET method in my ajax code

Comment: What is the full request URL shown in your network inspector when you see this error?

Comment: Also, is the code that you're showing us for `save_answer_in_session.php` the _full_ and _exact_ code copy/pasted from your editor? Because the error mentions line 5, but in the code above, that is an empty line.  We can only help if you show us your _actual_ code.